# Is SSL adequate enough to keep a website safe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I’ve been looking into programming a website for a company (no data or information other than forms are on it) I’ve been looking at BlueHost as a hosting and the SSL secure feature for security, I don’t know any other securing or encrypting myself, will BlueHosts SSL be enough?

Comment: SSL doesn't keep your site safe. It just keeps information being transmistted between your users and yourself safe.

Comment: If you think safety and security are just a matter of checking some boxes, then your approach is severely flawed and you should get some help with your project.

Comment: I want to take the opportunity to point you to [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: BTW: SSL does not exist anymore, it became *TLS* in 1999 (ok, you can still implement the old version, but that does not make any sense).

Answer (score 2):

No.  SSL only protects data in transit from interception by a 3rd party-- and there are many factors to consider on how SSL is implemented required to decide if it even does that satisfactorily.

There are many countless facets of security that you must consider beyond how to make sure that data doesn't get read by someone else while it is being transmitted between a browser and a server over SSL.  Too many to elaborate on in a stackoverflow answer.  To put it in perspective, when I deploy a system that contains any sensitive data (I work for a payment processing company, but "sensitive" covers a lot more than just credit card numbers), I have to answer around 800 questions on a security audit.  Only about 30 of those questions relate to SSL and making sure SSL is implemented properly.  Then a team of experts have to review the implementation of such a system, deliberate, and vote unanimously that it meets requirements. Even after all that, routine security audits find potential vulnerabilities that were overlooked and must be mitigated.

No.  SSL by itself is not enough to consider a system "secure".  If it has data that needs SSL, it almost certainly has more needs than just SSL.

Comment: Agreed completely, but that last line sort of implies that HTTPS isn't necessary for general use cases.  It's important to point out that a major reason for HTTPS is ensuring that the data coming back is coming from a server authorized to send data for that domain... that it wasn't tampered with or replaced along the way.  Public WiFi installations very commonly inject their own scripts into pages to serve and replace ads.  If that isn't bad enough, these scripts are often insecure themselves and can have their own vulnerabilities that then get applied to all sites visited on that WiFi.

Comment: How about SiteLock security and CodeGuard with domain privacy protection? These are what I was wanting

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should have SSL. With that said, no, that is not enough.

So, what do you need? While it is true that there is a lot to cover, you clearly need to be pointed to the right direction...

As far as hosting provider goes, there are other features that you could be interested in:

- Backups (although, you probably can roll a solution yourself)
- Antimalware (although, if your site will not allow to upload files, it is less relevant)
- DDoS mitigations.

*I want to remind you that information security is not only confidentiality, it is also availability and integrity (and traceability).*

---

Please set up a test enviroment, on a local server, make sure it works. You can do security audits on that before they go the production enviroment. Remember that the sooner you discover the bugs, the cheaper it will be to fix them... thus, you do not want to discover them in production.

*Yeah, it is ok to not have HTTPS on the test enviroment. There is plenty to do besides that. And yeah, you should review the security in production too.*

Ideally there will be team doing test, and among those tests they might look for potential vulnerabilities. There are also security scanners that can help with that.

However, you should be writing secure code to begin with. Right?

---

I have to tell you, the server-side is more relevant than the tagged HTML and jQuery. The golden rule is to not trust the client. Remember that request might not be coming from an actual browser (despite what the user agent might say). You must do validation on the server. Even though it is also a good idea to validate in the client (for a better user experience and to safe network capacity), client-side validations are virtally irelvant for security.

That is not the same to say that there are not things that can improve the security that can be done client-side. For example, figerprinting a client can be useful to detect when the client is coming from an unusual source for a given user, rising a red flag (a partial fingerprint is possible server-side). Also you can do mitigations for screen-recorders/keyloggers/shoulder-surfing.

*There are also very specific cases where doing cryptography on the client makes sense. That is not the usual case. You probably do not need to do that. And in the odd case you do, please hire an expert.*

---

Anyway, these are some things that developers often overlook (this is by no means a complete list):

- Do not trust the client.
- Validate all input.
- Sanitize all output (considering where it is going to).
- Use prepared statements on database access.
- Specify character charsets (for HTML, server-side string manipulation, and both database storage and connections).
- Do proper authentication and access control.
- Store credentials properly.
- Stay up to date with browser security features.
- Use Cross-Origin Resource Sharing correctly.
- Use HttPOnly cookies when possible.
- Use a Service Worker and Web Cache properly.
- Log errors instead of showing them to the client.
- Have traceability for all modifications.

Also, consider two factor authentication.

You might also be interested in [OWASP Top Ten project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) and [OWASP Cheat Sheet Series](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries). Note: These are not a security check list, and are not a replacement for a security audit. They aren't gospel either, however if you are not to follow them, let it not be because you are unaware.

Finally let me point you to [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/), a Q&A site dedicated to information security (hence the name) sister to this one.

---

Addendum: If you are not developing a web application, but setting up a content management system instead, then you must keep it up to date. Also, research and apply security hardening for whatever it is you are using.